# How to open YAML file, change something and save it back in Go?

Tags: go, yaml

I need to change some values in YAML file from Go code. In my case, I need to change values.yaml file from Helm chart. Since that file can change, I do not structure of the whole file in advance (for example developers added new YAML sections in it in various projects). I just know how section that I want to change looks like.

I understand there is YAML library in Go (https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml). It will not do the job, because it assumes I know in advance structure of the file that I need to change. All examples are something like:
1. create struct
2. unmarshal YAML to struct
3. change
4. marshal and save back

It is not working for me since I do not know exact format of file, hence I cannot do step 1, create struct.

This is part of YAML file I am trying to change:

```
image:
  repository: nginx
  tag: stable
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

I understand this can be done with help of interface{}, but I do not understand how. Assuming that I understand struct, marshal/unmarshal YAML files, can someone provide code that will:
1. Load YAML file that has at least 20 entries in it and is of unknown structure
2. Change only 1 entry (in my case I want to change tag number for image section)
3. Save it back.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: With `go-yaml` it should be possible to parse it into a `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: That library does not require that you know the structure of your YAML. What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @bereal: `map[string]interface{}`, no, but , `map[interface{}]interface{}` yes.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
var v interface{}
err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, &v)
img, ok := v.["image"].(map[interface{}]interface{})
if ok {
   img["tag"] = "somevalue"
}
```

The yaml library I use unmarshals into map[interface{}]interface{}. You need to add the necessary error checking, type assertions, etc.

When done, you can `yaml.Marshal(v)` and write the result.